# Dynamically inserting javascript ad tag from third party will not center in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, prototypejs

I want to include an Ad Tag from a third party source that is generated via javascript which `document.writes` the code to display the ad. I have no control over this. 
I have it working on my end, BUT for the life of me I cannot get this to center in my DIV. It's like it busts out and  aligns left after my div. I can't fathom what is going on. "IF" I include this ad tag directly in the page inside the DIV, it centers. But I need to dynamically pass it some data before it requests the ad, so I Have to dynamically create it, but this is the issue. It displays, just aligned left outside the target DIV.

So, I am given a js tag with a src and that src generates a `document.write` that writes out an iframe.

```
var js_src = ("contents_of_the_src").gsub(/tie=/,'tie=' + random10_digit)
var js_script = new Element('script',{'src': js_src});
Event.observe($('myDiv'), 'load',  $('myDiv').insert({top : js_script}));
```

so the view in question is something like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
<script language="text/javascript">
 var js_src = ("contents_of_the_src").gsub(/tie=/,'tie=' + random10_digit)
 var js_script = new Element('script',{'src': js_src});
 Event.observe($('myDiv'), 'load',  $('myDiv').insert({top : js_script}));
</script>
</div>
```

I've tried moving the js out of the div, afterwards, and try to insert then. I tried to create a new DIV, center that, and write the ad tag to it. All left aligned and outside of the DIV.

any ideas/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving #myDiv iframe CSS properties of position: relative; display: block; and margin: auto? The default {display: inline} styling of iframe elements could be causing your positioning problem.

If this doesn't work, are you sure that Prototype is inserting your script element into the DOM as you'd expect? Would you mind checking element inspector to confirm exactly where in the document the iframe is being written?

Comment: The code I posted doesn't work after additional testing. Since the AD code -- which is a script tag with a specific source. That source brings in some code the document.writes. unfortunately I can't document.write after the page loads. I need to pass a param name/value into the src so it needs it before it fires off. This is creating the issue I believe. I try to dynamically create the script tag with the appended param I need to pass... etc.. and nothing is returned.

Comment: Hmm... I think your problem may be caused by document.write's need for an actively loading page conflicting with the fact that a div's 'load' event is actually just an extension of the body element's 'onload' event. Perhaps if you were to abandon the higher-level Prototype methods for native methods that fired immediately as the browser encountered them, you could solve your problem simply by calling your script creation code after the closing tag of the target div, and using the native myDiv.insertBefore() to replace your Prototype event.observe().